# ROS program controlling arduino via serial communication

Tags: ros, arduino, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on arduino and ros communication for few days and now I have an arduino code which have two subscribers as;

**ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub("red", redLED);**
**ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub2("yellow", yellowLED);**

So, when I input
"**rostopic pub red -r 1 std_msgs/UInt16 1000**"
it lights up the LED then waits 1 second and turns it off and does that at 1 Hz.

What I want to do is writing a ros code so that when I press up key on keyboard, this rostopic I mentioned above will be sent or the subscriber will be called, however it works.

How can I do that, which topics do I have to look at? Keep in mind that I have no experience with ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215626/ros-program-controlling-arduino-via-serial-communication/) by [oneevening](https://answers.ros.org/users/23483/oneevening/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may look at [key_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/key_teleop) which is used to publish velocity commands using keyboard.

You should write a publisher, and using key bindings, you should publish messages.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1